# JQuery DataTables - Set one column to take extra width

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am curious if there is a way to set one of the columns to 'absorb' any extra width. For instance, I want all the columns to have auto width to the smallest possible width that the data within allows (without text wrapping) and I want one column to expand to whatever width is necessary to fill the table to 100%.

Or if anyone knows how, to set the table width to automatically only take up the necessary width.

Comment: Added a "CSS" tag for you; I think this is a problem that could potentially be solved by people with strong CSS skills.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/gFa29/

```
table {width:100%;border:solid 2px #ddd;}
th, td {white-space:nowrap;border:solid 1px #eee;}
.fill {width:95%}
```

- set the table to 100% width
- set all cells to `nowrap`
- set one of the `td` or `th` cells to a high % width to absorb the extra space